# About regexp in emacs ediff-directories

Tags: emacs, regex, diff

I want to compare two directories which have similar hierarchy.

With "M-x ediff-directories" within Emacs, I was prompted to input a regexp to constrain the name of files I want to compare. For example, I want to compare the files whose name ends with .c or .h. Then I input ".*.[ch]", However, I find that it only take effects on the top level directory, but i want the regexp take effects on the files lied in all the sub-directories, no matter what the depth it is.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall, edif-dirs is not recursive. I haven't tried it myself, but [this package](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EdiffTrees) seems to do what you want:

> The EdiffTrees package is a simple frontend to EdiffMode to allow a
>   simpler comparison of two similar directory trees.
>
> I wrote this package because I often need to compare two different
>   versions of the same directory tree and ediff-directories is not very
>   helpful in this case. Specially when the directory trees to compare
>   are deep and only a few files have changed.
>
> For further instructions, please see the comentary in the file.

Alternatively, assuming you are on a unix-like OS, you can go into eshell mode (M-x eshell), and run:

```
diff -r dir1 dir2
```

Kind of a hack really, but hey, you're still in emacs!

Comment: diff -r, that's too un-emacs, :P

Comment: Heh, I know I know, but _technically_ eshell is still in emacs your honor, I swear! :)